# Security concerns with Microsoft Authenticator App - it can approve requests from locked iPhone?

Tags: security, entra-id, two-factor-authentication

We're using the Microsoft Authenticator App for providing Multi-factor authentication (MFA) to resources protected by Azure AD.

I noticed you can approve a request by swiping the push notification from a locked iPhone screen on iOS and approve a login request.

Isn't this really insecure? This means a bad actor can access do multi-factor approval from a locked phone from a browser that is pre-authenticated.

**Scenario A:**

A user is logged in on Windows 10 with the Azure AD account in Windows.

```
1. Bad actor tries to open a resource, in my case through Visual Studio; just click the already authenticated account (no password required).

2. Swipe the push on the users device (not uncommon to be on a desk inside the office)

3. Tap approve and you're in!
```

**Scenario B:**

A user have the password auto-filled in their browser.

```
1. The user open a resource, like Outlook Online, just click
login without entering password since it is auto-filled.

2. Swipe the push on the users device (not uncommon to be on a desk inside the office)

3. Tap approve and you're in!
```

UPDATE:

I can also open Internet Explorer and Edge and get right into O365 without ever typing a password just by having a computer (without login password) and a locked iPhone.

**View on locked screen (in Swedish):**

[image: View on locked screen]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your scenario, an actor has stolen both the users laptop and IPhone (which apparantly in Sweden is stored with the laptop)  and you've not configured either autofill or password storage settings in edge. You've also not configured any of the sensitive content on the locks screen settings.

But your contention is that the MFA app is the problem...

Your logic appears flawed.   The most obvious problem is that keeping the iPhone and laptop together defeats the point of MFA.  The app should be on a device separate from the laptop.

Comment: I think you misread the point. The app is on my iPhone and I'm using my laptop. Which means that if you have a Windows 10 laptop signed in you can login and access all content in Office 365 without enter any password at all. The credentials are auto-populated from Windows.

Comment: You don't need to steal it either. Just walk around an office and you'll see phones on desks everywhere. Just look for a phone and someone without a screen saver password and hey you're in.

Comment: Ahh so you've set up your device for seamless access  in which case you should have set up a windows hello multifactor Auth to log into the laptop.  The fact that your phones are sitting on desks, and pc that don't have locked screens when unattended, again doesn't point to MFA being a problem.  MFA doesn't make you secure, good security hygiene makes you secure.

Comment: Yeah I agree. In most cases you would have policies preventing access to the computer without locked screen etc. But I still think it is not a good default with MFA available from locked screen. Non-enterprise customers may not notice. My sms currently have higher protection.

Comment: So that _option_ is available, but that's not an app setting, it's a phone setting.

Answer (score -1):

It is, it basically defeats the purpose of MFA. That is way we don't use SMS messages anymore.

You should prevent this by hiding sensitive content from the lock screen (a built in feature of iOS).

For how to activate this centrally depends on the device management software that you use - Afaria, AirWatch or other.

Comment: We don't use sms because there is no way to guarantee that the recipient device is the only device receiving the message.